# The word of a Fairy

Tags: plot-explanation, the-magicians

In “The Art of the Deal” (*The Magicians* 3:10), the Fairy Queen revokes the bargain that Earth's last Fairies made with the McAllister family, and says regretfully that henceforth no one will trust a Fairy's word.

But didn't she previously (3:2 “Heroes and Morons”) lie to Fen and Eliot in presenting Fray as their daughter?  Or on that occasion did she only *imply* so by some sleight-of-words, without saying anything literally false?

Comment: I thought it was just that Faries will not break a deal they have made. But they are still fully capable of deception and trickery in normal discourse. Which is why you have to be really careful you are fully informed when making deals with them.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose technically they don't explicitly say she's their daughter:

> I require someone I trust to accompany you.
>   We call her Frail Human.
>   Fray for short.
>   Say hello, Fray.
>   I'd like you to meet your daughter.

So the Fairy Queen just said that she'd like them to meet their daughter; she didn't say Fray was her. Although it's questionable whether the literal claim that she wanted them to meet their daughter was true, either.

Also, Fray refers to Eliot as "Father", so that raises the question of whether that counts as the fairies being dishonest.

And there's also the question of whether there's a difference between lying and breaking a promise.

Comment: Fray is the one who reveals (after the Queen rejects her) that she is not their daughter, so maybe the Queen ordered her to lie, even if the Queen avoided telling lies herself.  But I'd bet we could find other bendings of the truth.

Comment: Just watched “Poached Eggs” again. The Queen says Fray betrayed her parents – which is odd, because didn't she foist Fray on them as her spy (if a mole planted so openly can be described as a spy) in the first place?